# How can a UDP Client and a packet sniffer run on the same machine?

Tags: wireshark, udp, packet-analysis, layer4, transport-protocol

In my understanding, if you have a UDP socket client that is bound to a particular port, then a second UDP client on the same machine can't bind to the same port.

If this is the case, then how can a packet sniffing program like Wireshark run on the same machine you have a UDP client without issues?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Packet sniffing applications tap into the lower layers of the network stack, not at the top like your UDP-using applications that connect to UDP at the top of the network stack.

Comment: Are you saying that the packet sniffing applications work at the network/routing layer?

Comment: Even lower than that. Most can capture the Data-Link frames.

Comment: @Fred Usually the packet capturing happens right on top of the NIC, ie. between layer 2 and 3.